# Err: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable using unaddressable value as I try to use BindQuery method

Tags: http, go, query-string

I am using [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) for creating the HTTP service trying to validate the entire query params received with the HTTP request and here is how am I doing with the `BindQuery` method but as I try to send the request with the URL having query parameters like `http://localhost:3003/user?id=ck5w9xc5g004d0892zwb07w5p`

```
type QueryUser struct {
   Id string `binding:"required" validate:"regexp=^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`
}

func (uhc UserHttpController) UserGet(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var queryUser QueryUser
    if err := ctx.BindQuery(queryUser); err != nil {

    } 
}
```

The program just crashes with error `reflect: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable using unaddressable value` at the statement `ctx.BindQuery(queryUser)`

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to prefix `&` and pass `&queryUser` when calling `BindQuery`.

```
type QueryUser struct {
     Id string `binding:"required" validate:"regexp=^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`
}

func (uhc UserHttpController) UserGet(ctx *gin.Context) {
   var queryUser QueryUser
   if err := ctx.BindQuery(&queryUser); err != nil {

    } 
}
```